# VT-X is not available to enable HAXM for Android

Tags: android

I want to learn android. I am using windows 7. I have installed android studio. Trying my first "hello world" app and it's giving me an error while running the emulator that HAXM is not available. My PC has no vt-x to enable. Intel virtualization Technology is not supported in my pc. Is there a way to run emulator without HAXM?

Answer (score 0):

The Android emulator does not require Intel HAXM. But you then must use the ARM image instead of the x86 HAXM image. (Use ARM as the CPU for your virtual device - from the AVD manager)